# Working with Zookeeper

Tags: scala, apache-zookeeper

This is the first time I use Zookeeper and I use Scala as my programming language. Does Zookeeper support Scala? If not, is there any workaround solution?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - it's just another Java lib and Scala is compatible with Java libs in general.  I've done a project using Zookeeper and Scala and it works great.   I'm using [Curator](https://github.com/Netflix/curator/wiki) as my client library which is built using Java, but there is also Twitter's [scala-zookeeper-client](https://github.com/twitter/scala-zookeeper-client).   Or you could use the Zookeeper client API directly.

Kafka, a well-known Scala open source project, uses Zookeeper.